# How do I prepend variable to open file stream when using split to create csv's?

Tags: bash, shell, split

I have a bash file that takes a large csv and splits the csv into smaller csv's based on this blog https://medium.com/swlh/automatic-s3-file-splitter-620d04b6e81c. It works well as it is fast never downloading the csv's which is great for a lambda. The csv's after they split do not have headers only the originating csv. This is problem for me since I am not able to read with apache pyspark a set of files one with header row and many other files without header rows.

I want to add a header row to each csv written.

What the code does

INFILE

- "s3//test-bucket/test.csv"

OUTFILES - split into 300K lines

- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.00.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.01.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.02.csv"
- "s3//dest-test-bucket/test.03.csv"

[AWS documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-copy)

> You can use the dash parameter for file streaming to standard input (stdin) or standard output (stdout).

I don't know if this is even possible with an open file stream.

Original code that works

```bash
LINECOUNT=300000
INFILE=s3://"${S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"

FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"  | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))
```

This was my attempt to add a variable to outgoing file stream, but it did not work.

```bash
LINECOUNT=300000
INFILE=s3://"${S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_S3_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"

HEADER=$(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | head -n 1)

FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -l ${LINECOUNT} --filter "echo ${HEADER}; aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"  | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))
```

Comment: The script in that article you reference has some beginner mistakes that will cause breakage and/or security issues given some input and some environment settings, don't use it. If you'd like to know how to split a CSV, post a question with a sample CSV and expected output.

Comment: One line sentence is mandatory? With several lines and iterations it will be readable and elegant

Comment: one line is not necessary as long as it is streaming and not downloaded to the local machine which would cause out of memory exceptions